# Nested ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I want to create a cart which has `Nested array`.
Like my parent array has items and child array has item's respective toppings but when i add toppings to my item array it automatically add same toppings to all index of items array. Here is my image:

[image]

Here i'm attaching my code below

**Item_Array**

```
private void addNewToppinDialoge(ProductsModel.Datum datum, int adapterPosition) {

    ProductOrderModel.Datum productOrderModel = new ProductOrderModel.Datum();
    productOrderModel.setCategoryID(datum.getProductID());
    productOrderModel.setCategory(datum.getProductName());
    int i = productActivity.productOrderModelArrayList.size();
    int j = i + 1;
    productOrderModel.setSrNO(String.valueOf(j));

    productActivity.productOrderModelArrayList.add(productOrderModel);
    productActivity.refreshOrderAdapter();
    productActivity.changeTitleToolbar(datum.getProductName());

}
```

**Toppings_array**

```
private void addToppingToCart(ToppingsModel.Datum.LookupValue lookupValue, int adapterPosition) {
    ProductOrderModel.Datum datum = new ProductOrderModel.Datum();
    ProductOrderModel.Datum.SubCategory subCategory = new ProductOrderModel.Datum.SubCategory();
    subCategory.setCategory(lookupValue.getLookupvalue());

    int pos = productActivity.productOrderModelArrayList.size() - 1;
    Log.e("POS", String.valueOf(ProductActivity.productOrderModelArrayList.size() - 1));

    productActivity.productOrderModelArrayListSub.add(subCategory);
    int subPos = productActivity.productOrderModelArrayListSub.size() - 1;

    productActivity.productOrderModelArrayListSub.get(subPos).setCategory(lookupValue.getLookupvalue());

    productActivity.productOrderModelArrayList.get(pos).setSubCategory(productActivity.productOrderModelArrayListSub);

    productActivity.refreshOrderAdapter();
}
```

**Adapter For Cart**

```
 public class MyOrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyOrderAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static ToppingsListAdapter toppingsListAdapter;
    static Context mContext;
    ArrayList<ProductOrderModel.Datum> orderModelArrayList;

    public MyOrderAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<ProductOrderModel.Datum> orderModelArrayList) {
        MyOrderAdapter.mContext = mContext;
        this.orderModelArrayList = orderModelArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyOrderAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.myorder_layout, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyOrderAdapter.ViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyOrderAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int i) {

        holder.mTextOrderName.setText(orderModelArrayList.get(i).getCategory());

        holder.mImageRemove.setOnClickListener(v -> removeItem(orderModelArrayList.get(i), holder.getAdapterPosition()));
        holder.mTextSerialNo.setText(orderModelArrayList.get(i).getSrNO() + ".");

        ArrayList<ProductOrderModel.Datum.SubCategory> arrayItem = (ArrayList<ProductOrderModel.Datum.SubCategory>) orderModelArrayList.get(i).getSubCategory();
        if (arrayItem == null) {

        } else {
            toppingsListAdapter = new ToppingsListAdapter(mContext, arrayItem);
            holder.mRecyclerToppings.setAdapter(toppingsListAdapter);

        }

    }

    protected void removeItem(ProductOrderModel.Datum productOrderModel, int adapterPosition) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orderModelArrayList.size();
    }

    public void refreshAdapter() {
        toppingsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public RecyclerView mRecyclerToppings;
        private TextView mTextOrderName, mTextSerialNo;
        private ImageView mImageRemove;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTextOrderName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderItemName);
            mImageRemove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderRemove);
            mTextSerialNo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.srno);

            mRecyclerToppings = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_toppings);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false);
            mRecyclerToppings.setLayoutManager(manager);
        }

        public int getAdapterPosition(ProductOrderModel.Datum.SubCategory remove) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

strong text:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to header and footer of `RecyclerView`. Here is the code.

**Try this one:**

```
public class HeaderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    String[] data;

    public HeaderAdapter(String[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
            return new VHItem(null);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
            return new VHHeader(null);
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof VHItem) {
            String dataItem = getItem(position);
            //cast holder to VHItem and set data
        } else if (holder instanceof VHHeader) {
            //cast holder to VHHeader and set data for header.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (isPositionHeader(position))
            return TYPE_HEADER;

        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    private boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }

    private String getItem(int position) {
        return data[position - 1];
    }

    class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;

        public VHItem(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Button button;

        public VHHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope this is not the correct way i'm stucked in array not in adapter

Comment: @AliasgarPatel you should add your toppings array items in footer and and item in header! And in your bindings you frequently re initiate your adapter every time!! Why! it's should be in your constructor.

Comment: Problem is in your adapter not in array list.

Comment: I also have 2 nested recyclerview. you can see method @BindViewHolder in Adapter which set another recyclerview adapter

Comment: @AliasgarPatel this is not actual way brother! Try to use my adapter or like that.

Comment: answer for this question is i was not re-initializing my toppings arraylist while inserting a new data ... btw thankyou for your response